# What does Qt stand for?

Tags: qt, acronym

I am a fan of Qt and the more i learn about it, the more i love it. I don't know why it is named Qt. I searched it but all of the results where irrelevant. Most were acronyms like "Quality Time" and some were "cutie" or "quiet".

I thought may be it is a funny acronym like "GNU" which is GNU's not UNIX. Either way it is such a cool and cute name. Anybody know about it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Quote from the first edition of `C++ gui programming with Qt 4`:

> The letter ‘Q’ was chosen as the class prefix because the letter looked beautiful
>   in Haavard’s Emacs font. The ‘t’ was added to stand for “toolkit”, inspired by
>   Xt, the X Toolkit.

*Haavard Nord and Eirik Chambe-Eng began the development of Qt

The same piece of history is on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_%28software%29#History)

Comment: Cool. So Q was only chosen because it's cute :)

Comment: @Nejat: Yes, and "Qt" is also pronounced "Cute" ;)

Answer (score 2):

"The letter ‘Q’ was chosen as the class prefix because the letter looked beautiful in Haavard’s Emacs font. The ‘t’ was added to stand for “toolkit”, inspired by Xt, the X Toolkit. The company was incorporated on March 4, 1994, originally as ***Quasar Technologies***, then as Troll Tech, and today as Trolltech."

So it should be Quasar Toolkit.

References: 1.https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20130907190045AAZZ9uM
            2.http://formfull.in/qt